# Where do I find the environment entry mapping screen in Weblogic?

Tags: weblogic, application-server, oc4j

I am trying to migrate an application from OC4J to Weblogic, but I can not find the environment entry mapping screen in Weblogic 12c.

Is there one? If so, where is it? If not, how do I do it?

Our app has the following values in the web.xml:

```
<env-entry>
   <env-entry-name>SERVLET_PATH</env-entry-name>
   <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
</env-entry>
<env-entry>
   <env-entry-name>USER</env-entry-name>
   <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
</env-entry>
<env-entry>
   <env-entry-name>PASSWORD</env-entry-name>
   <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
</env-entry>
```

In OC4J these can been seen in the Environment Entry Mappings screen. (Also I can see them in Websphere under the Environment entries for Web modules screen)

Thanks

[Edit]
Thanks to JoseK I was able to find the answer.

Once I had created the plan.xml, I found out that I need to add a  and a   to the plan.xml:

```
<variable-definition>
  <variable>
    <name>SERVLET_PATH</name>
    <value>http://203.15.228.111:7001/RailExchangeServlet/servlet/RailExchangeServlet</value>
  </variable>
</variable-definition>
```

...

```
<module-descriptor external="false">
  <root-element>web-app</root-element>
  <uri>WEB-INF/web.xml</uri>
  <variable-assignment>
    <name>SERVLET_PATH</name> <!-- this links to the variable-definition name -->
    <xpath>/web-app/env-entry[env-entry-name="SERVLET_PATH"]/env-entry-value</xpath>
  </variable-assignment>
</module-descriptor>
</module-override>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In earlier versions of Weblogic you could view and edit the web.xml values from the console.

In WL10 onwards you don't get to view this from the console, and instead there is a concept of a Deployment Plan (saved on filesystem as Plan.xml)

In that file you can specify **over-riding values on the web.xml** which will change from env to env.

An example is here

http://biemond.blogspot.in/2009/04/using-weblogic-deployment-plan-to.html

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1107834&tstart=0

and some reading

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/deployment/config.html#wp1057141

Comment: Thanks for that. I will check it out on Monday. So the plan.xml is not part of the ear file and when I deploy the app, somewhere in the console I can point it to the plan.xml, the plan.xml is not part of the ear - is this right?

Comment: yes. Once you deploy it, you go into `Configuration` and hit `Save` - this will create a basic `Plan.xml` on the file system (outside of the EAR) which you can edit later.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Hopefully one last question, how do I get weblogic to reload the Plan.xml? I've tried restarting the app, but it didnt work...

Comment: From the admin console I think http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/deployment/redeploy.html#wp1031505